# Order statistics of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $\{I_1, I_2, \dotsc, I_N\}$ be $N$ i.i.d random variables. I know that the smallest [orders statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) and the largest one are defined respectively as follow:

$$I_{(1)}=\min(\{I_1, I_2, \dotsc, I_N\}).$$
$$I_{(N)}=\max(\{I_1, I_2, \dotsc, I_N\}).$$

I want to find the order statistics number $k$. In fact, I saw in a paper that for $1<k<N$, we have:

$$I_{(k)}=\min(\{I_1, I_2, \dotsc, I_N\}\backslash\{I_{(1)}, I_{(2)}, \dotsc, I_{(k-1)}\}).$$

How to get this result? How to prove it? Or it is obvious?

Comment: Isn't this the natural *definition* of the kth-smallest value (when the values are all distinct)?

Comment: $I_{(k)}=\min(\{I_1, I_2, \dotsc, I_N\}\backslash\{I_{(1)}, I_{(2)}, \dotsc, I_{(k-1)}\})$ simply says the smallest remaining element of the set after the $k-1$ smallest members of the original set has been removed.  Apart from duplicate values, this seems rather obvious, and if there are duplicate values then the definition is not going to work and indeed you may have problems with $\{I_1, I_2, \dotsc, I_N\}$

Comment: This is only true if the values are distinct. In that case, I'm not really sure what it is you want proven: it depends on how formal/pedantic you want to be.

Comment: Yes thank you all. I was wrong. It is obvious.

Comment: Then close? $ $